# Location services doesnt work on Lion os x

Tags: objective-c, macos, osx-lion

A simple location services program was working fine on my machine and suddenly stopped working. upon further exploring the problem, i realized that some process has disabled location services in system preferences->security & privacy->privacy

I checked "enable location services", but again it got disabled automatically.

after some research, i found that, its not just my program, even built-in system functions also failing because of this problem, ex: system preferences->date & time->time zone failed to get current location,

everytime i check "enable location services", i see following error in console logs:

```
16/10/12 11:23:15.636 AM [0x0-0x42042].com.apple.systempreferences: ERROR,Time,372059595.636,Function,"CLInternalSetLocationServicesEnabled",CLInternalSetLocationServicesEnabled failed
16/10/12 11:23:15.638 AM [0x0-0x42042].com.apple.systempreferences: STACK,Time,372059595.636,1   CoreLocation                        0x00007fff8f9957be CLInternalSetLocationServicesEnabled + 110
```

few other pointers:
-wifi is ON. 
-I didn't install ios simulator, 
-i use xcode Version 4.5(4G182),
-i use boot camp and made my mbp dual boot(mac lion and win7)
-i do only mac development but not ios

can someone help me?